# Photoshop on WINE 1.4

Tags: 12.04, wine, photoshop

I've encountered a problem that seems it didn't happen to anyone other than me :s I've Downloaded PS CS6 and Installed it with no problems, When I try to launch it via WINE 1.4 it freezes on "Scannin for plugins" :s

PS.. I did add atmlib.dll and msvcr80.dll to the system32 folder and usin 12.04 LTS :)

Is there a solution :?

Comment: look, sorry for this not professional answer, i am not sure, but i runnung pes2013 on ubuntu using virtual box. maybe if you can install it in virtual box, but dont be angry beacause this is not professionaly answered.

Comment: Are you using a cracked version of photoshop?

Comment: @Sameer Not Really mate.. Its the trial one :s
I wanted to try before Installing

Comment: @DimitrisTheodoridis I could do this workaround.. if I couldn't find another way..

Comment: I use Virtualbox all the time. I have an older Photoshop running under Wine. At first that worked fine, but after adding fonts things went wrong. The VM works fine, just XP, although it slows the host down a lot. I thought there is a (affordable) paid Wine version that offers Photoshop support.

Comment: http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Install Oracle Virtualbox [Its Free]
2. Install windowx xp / 7
3. Install Photoshop in virtual machine

**Sugesstion**

Photoshop and alot of big softwares does not works well in wine so use vbox (Virtual Box)

Comment: As what @Dimitris said.. Seems like the best Solution :s

Comment: yes thats what i do on my LApyy i use xp and ps3 and it works like charm on Vbox and even i use illustrator and they work flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

install ps using playonlinux (it's in the software center) it works flawless.